# How to Refresh MatTable Data after upload file

Tags: angular, file-upload, rxjs, angular-material

[image]i'm new in Angular since a week i'm facing an anoying issue that i'cant fix it.
After uploading a file in my backend to insert users from a compagny, my MatTable doesn't refresh automatically by itself, I need to reload the page to see users has been added. I've search actually almost everything about this topic but none of them helped me. I have two components (fileUpload and listUser rendered in same route). Even when i'm calling my getUsers() rest api method , nothing change. By advance thank's for the helps and sharing knowledge.

## ***UserService.ts***

```
export class UserService {

  public refreshList$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<IUsers[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<IUsers[]>(`${BASEURL}/list`)
      .pipe(
        map((users) => {
          console.log(users);
          return users;
        })
      );
  }

  uploadFile(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    return this.http
      .post<HttpEvent<any>>(`${BASEURLL}/upload`, formData, {
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'json'
      });
  }
```

## ***FileUploadComponent.ts***

```
export class FileUploadComponent {

  @Output() emitUpload : EventEmitter<BehaviorSubject<boolean>> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private user: UserService) { }

  upload(): void {
    // ignore upload file process..
  
    this.user.refreshList$.next(false); // try to notify upload has been done to call getList()
    this.emitUpload.emit(this.user.refreshList$); // FileUploadComponent.ts is a child of my listComponent.ts
  }

}
```

## ***ListUserComponent***

```
export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit{ 
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['username', 'lastName', 'firstName'];
  users : IUsers[];
  usersDataSource: MatTableDataSource<IUsers>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator !: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private user: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserList(); // get my users when component is rendered
    console.log(this.user.refreshList$.getValue()); // try to get value of my Behavior
  }

  getUserList() {  
        this.user.getUsers().subscribe(
          (users) => {
          console.log(users);
          this.users = users;
            this.usersDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IUsers>(copyOf(this.users));
            this.usersDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          }, 
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
       )
  }

  refreshTable(event: BehaviorSubject<boolean>){
    console.log(event.getValue()); // get the new value of behaviorSubject after file upload successfully 
    event.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("Get new value");
      //this.getUserList();
    });
  }

}
```

## ***ListUserComponent.html***

```
 <div class="table-agency col-8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="users">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Username </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.username }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.LastName }} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> firstName </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firsName}} </td>
    </ng-container> 
  </table> 
  
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5]" showFirstLastButtons> </mat- 
  paginator> 
 </div>

   <app-FileUpload (emitUpload)="refreshTable($event)"></app-FileUpload>
```

Comment: the HTML is missing, can you add it please?

Comment: Hi Than'ks for the help, i've added my List template. But i'dont think the problem comes from html. Like i said, even when i'm trying to call my getUsersList() to get the new datas, nothing change, but when i'm trying in Postam , I get the new datas inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who got the same problem, i finally found a solution. Add a short timer before calling the list.  Bellow the way it looks like :

1. Add a Subject and an Observable in your service to notify when there some change

***UserService.ts***

```
  private _refresh$ = new Subject<any>();

  get refresh$(){
    return this._refresh$; // Will push value when any changes happend
  }

  listen(): Observable<any> {
    return this._refresh$.asObservable(); // Will listen for the value that was pushed
  }
```

2. From method you need to perform , push a value using your Subject created in your Service

***FileUpload.component.ts***

```
upload(){
  //process to upload file 
  this.user.refresh$.next('uploaded'); // When the file is uploaded, push a value by using your Subject created in your Service.
}
```

3. From another method, listen the value that has been pushed by your subject and add a short timer before calling your refreshed list

***ListUser.component.ts***

```
 constructor(private user: UserService) { }
 ngOnInit() {
    
    /* From your service, call your listen method created previously, responsible 
    to get the value pushed by the "_refresh$". Then add a timer (Ex: 500ms) before 
    calling your list */
    this.user.listen().pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(() => {
         this.getUsers();
    });
  }
  // When we finish with our Subject, will unsubscribe for performance reason (Release memory space) 
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.user.refresh$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Hopefully it will help. If someone got a better solution let me know, Thank's by advance.

Answer (score 0):

as of how Material Tables works, you need to inform the table that something has changed (for performance reasons)
`this.table.renderRows();` see example: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-dynamic-array-data

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, still got the problem. But things is very strange, even I'm calling the getUsers() method, I have the same result. When I call my list before and after the download file, it returns me the same result as nothing happened. But when I test with Postamn, I have new results. I saw a possible solution like auto reload the page using (windows.location..) or try the changeDetector but I definitly don't want to use them for performance and user experience reasons.

Comment: probably you are refreshing the table when the upload is still not finished. Your code is incomplete so it's hard to tell. But if you have 6 items and after the upload you still have 6 items, either you have a server problem or you do the GET request while the upload is not completed or still not written in the DB.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help. Yes your right, I finally found a solution yesterday. I've shared the code bellow of the post. As you noticed, the problem was I'called my list before the file uploaded completely, so I've just added a short Timer before calling my list.

Comment: that's more a workaround an not a real solution. If your server is busy or your connection is slow, it could take more that 500ms.
you should not render ListUser component before you got an answer from the server that the user is was successfully saved.